# Efficient tile maps in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, tilemap, corona-sdk

I need to create a tile map based level system for Corona SDK that loads files created with Tiled [1]. It also needs to support user touch scrolling and zooming.

I've searched the Corona forums for possible solutions but the ones they talk about don't convince me. They basically have a matrix of Sprite objects which have an image loaded and a given position. That makes scrolling and zooming a bit hard.

Any better ideas?

[1] http://www.mapeditor.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, have you already seen Lime but don't want to incorporate that framework, since its entire purpose is to incorporate Tiled maps in Corona:

http://lime.outlawgametools.com/

In your searches of the Corona forums, did you find these threads?

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/01/29/object-culling-render-process-when-not-content-area

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/02/03/screen-culling

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/03/24/tilemap-using-spritesheet-very-slow-device-any-help

A while ago someone had asked about developing efficient tile map performance/culling and I provided an example of one simple approach using quadrants to organize the tiles for efficiency. Then p120ph37 showed up with an even more efficient technique that changes the frame of the sprite objects without actually showing/hiding sprites.

---

What a coinciendence: just yesterday I saw this preview of the improved tiling performance in Corona's latest build.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzdjNDcn2gE

Comment: 1st link is dead.

Comment: thanks, I updated the link. it appears to have gone open-source

Answer (score 0):

check this out running @ 60fps : http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/33119-million-tile-engine-beta-release/

and should only get better when Corona Graphics 2.0 gets released.

Comment: You should add more to your answer instead of just posting a link.

Comment: As far as I can see, this really isn't relevant to the question - the question asks for better ways of doing it, whilst you've just linked to a video showing it can be done. On top of that, this question was posted over a year ago, so it's likely no longer relevant (new versions come out, etc.) Finally, welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: The link was meant to use "Million Tite Engine" which is a very good map engine for CoronaSDK, even better than "Lime" mentioned in the first answer (even in Lime website, it says MTE should be a better solution as a map engine).